# GLSL fragment shader freezes the whole program

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

After a lot of debugging I found the lines in my shader code that stop the game from even loading correctly:

```
out_Color =  vec4(totalDiffuse,1.0) * textureColour + vec4(totalSpecular,1.0);
out_Color = mix(vec4(skyColour,1.0), out_Color, visibility);
out_Color = vec4(pass_tangent, 1.0);
```

where out_Color is the output of the fragment shader. The code works when I either comment out the tangent or the mixing of the out_Color with the sky color. I also know that it is unnecessary to calculate out_Color, only to set it to the tangent, but it is just for debug purposes.
BTW, I am using lwjgl (Java) for the stuff around, if that's important.

EDIT:
It freezes not only when set to be a tangent, but any color!

Comment: You are overridding value of Out_color with each of the statement i think driver is trying some optimizations that resulting in this behaviour.  Try adding Out_color += your statement; see if issue resolves. Also give more code.

Comment: @Patroshi Kulkarni Driver issue was my guess too. If you want to see more code, look at the ThinMatrix Video Tutorials for OpenGL. It is not important to this issue, since the error still occurred, when I commented out all the calculations

Comment: Are you sure that you don't get any compile/link errors for the shader/program?

Comment: @derhass yes, no errors

Comment: well, show the actual source code. I can imagine a lot of stuff going wring here.